# BizTalk 2013 file transfer converts pdf to xml when uploading to site

Tags: xml, ftp, sharepoint-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013

[image]

I just set up a BizTalk 2013 developers edition to be able to learn more.

I also did set up SharePoint foundation 2013 for file transfers etc.

I have a file transfer from a ftp to a site on my SharePoint. 
It picks up the file and then converts it to .xml when it uploads it to the site.

I use the standard built in passthrutransmit pipelines.
Type on the send port is windows sharepoint services ofc.

Send handler is biztalkserverapplication.

How can I fix so it uploads the pdf in pdf format? That will say without modifying it in any way?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand if you are using a passthrutransmit pipeline BizTalk doesn't even serialize the message what do you mean by a pdf in pdf format ? you mean its name in output ? i don't get it

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in any way. The file I upload to the ftp is in PDF and when the filetransfer moves it to Sharepoint it converts its to .xml. Thats the problem. I want it to be .pdf all the way.

Comment: Ah i see, Can you show me a screen shot of your send port config ?

Comment: I attached 2 screenshots with send port and adapter config.

Comment: Had to change the "Filename propertie" under windows sharepoint services transport properties to %Filename%.pdf on the sendport and it works as  I wished.

Comment: Moderater, can you change this thread / post to answered as I just posted what needed to be done but got an answer ban going on my account.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the "Filename property" under windows SharePoint services transport properties to `%Filename%.pdf` on the sendport.